# Send array via RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp, php-amqplib

How can I send an array of messages using RabbitMQ?
I do not want to send every message separately.

For example:

```
ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer('hello world'));
```

How could I use something like:

```
ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer([msg1, msg2, msg3...]));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass JSON through like so:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(json));
```

Then the consumer would parse the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I send array of messages using RabbitMQ? I do not want to send every message separately.

You can't. Each message must be sent individually.

If you tried to do what you want, you would end up with a single "message" that contained all of the individual messages you wanted to send.

If you want to make an API that looks like you can do this, just create a function that takes an array of messages, loops through them and sends them one at a time.

(nodejs / amqplib)

```
function publishAll(ex, ...messages){
  return messages.map((msg) => {
    ch.publish(ex, '', msg);
  });
}

var pub = publishAll("my.exchange", [msg1, msg2, msg3]);
pub.then(() => {
  // run code after they are all published
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I addition to what @derick-bailey said, if you need more than one variable to be sent in each message you could always make a string with the variables comma separated. Or, if you'll use commas in the text you can find some other symbol that will work.